# What is the query and index used by RavenStudio to aggregate the document types shown in the Collections tab?

Tags: ravendb

I would like to get the Raven-Clr type for each the documents in my Raven database.  I have tried the following index, but am only retrieving the document Id:

Map:

```
from doc in docs 
let DocumentType = doc[""@metadata""][""Raven-Entity-Name""]
let Id = doc[""@metadata""][""Id""]
let LastModified = (DateTime)doc[""@metadata""][""Last-Modified""]
select new {DocumentType = doc[""@metadata""][""Raven-Entity-Name""], Id, LastModified}
```

Transform:

```
from result in results
            select new {Id = result.Id, DocumentType = result.DocumentType, LastModified = result.LastModified}
```

My goal is to get document meta data and display a distinct list of collection / document type like the RavenStudio.  I want to create a projection and populate a list of the following class:

```
public class MetaDocument
{
  public string Id{get; set;}
  public string DocumentType {get; set;}
  public DateTime LastModified {get; set;}
}
```

I can only get the doc id, and the other values are returned as null.

**Note**
I checked the Raven-Entity-Name as Fitzchak suggested.  It is populates.

**Edit**

I found [this approach on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/rtCTvW3Giy4/mhoqmlR9ozMJ) where the Map is altered to contain

```
DocumentType = ((dynamic)doc)[""@metadata""][""Raven-Entity-Name""]
```

Result is the same.

**Edit 2**

I examined the query results in RavenStudio and the projection itself contains null for both LastModified and DocumentType.  Do these fields need to be stored in order to be accessible?

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB Studio uses the `Raven/DocumentsByEntityName` index, which is created by the studio (by default). It is a simple index (map only).

Map:

```
from doc in docs 
let Tag = doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"]
select new { Tag, LastModified = (DateTime)doc["@metadata"]["Last-Modified"] };
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this but pull back null when I reference Tag.  In other words, I can query and get the ids for the docs, but when I try to get the actual Tag value, I get a null.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't set the "Raven-Entity-Name" metadata item on your documents. The client API handles this for you, but if you're using the raw http api, you should set this value by yourself.

Comment: "Raven-Entity-Name" is set appropriately on the documents.  I am after the Raven-Entity-Name, not the doc itself.  I thought I could make a projection to get the Id, Entity-Name (DocumentType) and LastModified.  My projection only returns the Id.